# OpenMP task reduction with target offloading segfaults when running single threaded

Tags: c++, clang, openmp, nvidia, offloading

I was using OpenMP with target offload and found that my application segfaults when limiting OpenMP to a single thread.
I could boil it down to the following snippet:

```
#include <omp.h>

int main(){
    int res = 0;

    #pragma omp parallel num_threads(1)
    {
        #pragma omp single
        {
            #pragma omp taskgroup task_reduction(+:res)
            {
                #pragma omp target in_reduction(+:res) nowait
                {
                    res++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Compiled with

```
clang++ -fopenmp -fopenmp-targets=nvptx64 --offload-arch=sm_61 -O0 main.cpp
```

using `clang 17.0.0` and `cuda 12.1`, ran on a Ubuntu 22.04 machine with a 12700k/1080Ti.

This segfaults when `num_threads` is set to `1`, but works fine with more than one thread (e.g. `num_threads(2)`) or when not specifying `nowait` on the target task, so that it synchronizes at the end of the target region.

From my understanding, this should work just fine even with a single thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to mailing list/github issues, as of writing this, support for `in_reduction` in clang is incomplete/missing.